# How to update data into table in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

What will be the equivalent statement in grail for this query

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET ADDRESS = 'Pune' WHERE ID = 6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options depending on what you are trying to achieve, but the most direct way would be like this:

```
def customer = Customers.get(6)
customer.address = 'Pune'
customer.save(flush:true)
```

Note that you may need to check for failed validation, missing Customer and so on.